# Can you remotely update a developmental iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, deployment

If someone has a development version of my iPhone application, is it possible to send that device an update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you're using the ad-hoc distribution, that's not possible. You have to resend the file per mail or any other medium and they have to update it manually via itunes.

Comment: Ok...I figured as much...can I send the application as a whole and have them update since they don't have the sdk and can't deploy to the device?

Comment: you can send the .app file or create a folder named "payload", put your .app file in it, zip it and change the extension to .ipa, though itunes can handle both file types. they don't have to install the sdk.